# Use selected dropdown list value to change HTML Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want it so that when the DropDown List element is selected, I am able to grab it's value and set the input text, or even a DIV text, or even a label text to the value that was selected. Why doesn't it work? What am I missing?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fob6kp6k/

HTML:

```
<select id="bonus">
<option value="1">-$5000</option>
<option value="2">-$2500</option>
<option value="3">$0</option>
<option value="4">$1</option>
<option value="5">We really appreciate your work</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenControl" runat="server" />
```

JS/JQ:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bonus').change(function() {
    document.getElementById("hiddenControl").value = $("#bonus option:selected").text());
  });  
});
```

whole thing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bonus').change(function() {
    document.getElementById("hiddenControl").value = $("#bonus option:selected").text());
  });  
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="bonus">
<option value="1">-$5000</option>
<option value="2">-$2500</option>
<option value="3">$0</option>
<option value="4">$1</option>
<option value="5">We really appreciate your work</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenControl" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an extra `)` in the line where you are setting the value. You need to update from

```
 document.getElementById("hiddenControl").value = $("#bonus option:selected").text());
```

to

```
 document.getElementById("hiddenControl").value = $("#bonus option:selected").text();
```

However, as you are using jquery, you should update it further to following

```
 $("#hiddenControl").val($("#bonus option:selected").text());
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/3paUZ4wT4GZwZFuCL7Bj?p=preview

Comment: NVM Working now! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the below changes to make it working

```
$('#bonus').change(function () {
    var text = $("#bonus").find(":selected").text();
    $("#hiddenControl").val(text);
});
```